# Angular: Importing dates with different time zones from Excel

Tags: excel, angular, typescript, js-xlsx

I am using https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/ with Angular 7 to import excel file and do some processing before I send it over to the server. My function for reading Excel data is:

```
private readFile(file: any, dataType: string) {

 let fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

 fileReader.onload = (e) => {
   this.arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
   let data = new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer);
   let arr = new Array();
   for (let i = 0; i !== data.length; ++i) { arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]); }
   let bstr = arr.join('');
   let workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary', cellDates: true});
   let firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
   let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName];
   let jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);
   this.mapExcelModal.show(jsonData);
 };

 fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

I have a problem with reading data that contains dates if it is in a different time zone. For example, I enter data in the Excel file as 28/02/2019 and that date is read as `Wed Feb 27 2019 23:59:20 GMT+0200 (Israel Standard Time)`.
If I try to import it from my local machine I get `Thu Feb 28 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`. I need to just read the dates regardless of the time zone, I need to parse it as `2019-02-28T00:00:00Z` format. I use momentjs for formatting. I dont understand why does it read the date as day before and how to handle it so that the time zone doesn't affect the date? Any suggestions?

Comment: Best way to handle timezone issue is to store the date always in `GMT` format and then render it as per the required format later. anyway, it's difficult to say where exactly is the date getting converted to local timezone from the ts code you have posted. can you reproduce the issue on `StackBlitz`,https://stackblitz.com/ and the share the link here

Comment: The problem is that I get it like that from Excel before I store it anywhere. I just read the Excel file and parse it into json using the function I posted and the date is read as Wed Feb 27 2019 23:59:20 GMT+0200 (Israel Standard Time). I think that local settings for Excel is to blame here but I need a way to go around that.